# Factoring out functions into utility modules causes errors "Parameter implicitly has an 'any' type"

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm fairly new to React/Typescript and I cannot seem to resolve this error any time I move a function into a separate module and export/import it. I'm defining all parameter types and it all works when in the same file, so I wonder if it's something around the build process but I'm not sure where to look. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's a stripped down example:

(components/Course.tsx)

```
import CourseModel from '../models/CourseModel';
import { displayCourseLevel } from '../utils/display';

type CourseProps = {
    course: CourseModel;
}

function Course({ course }: CourseProps): JSX.Element { 

    return (
        <>
            <div>Level: {displayCourseLevel(course.Level)}</div>
        </>
    );
}

export default Course;
```

(utils/display.ts)

```
function displayCourseLevel(level: number): string { 
    switch (level) {
        case 1:
            return "Introductory";
        case 2:
            return "Intermediate";
        case 3:
            return "Advanced";
        default:
            return "N/A";
    }
}

export { displayCourseLevel }
```

This throws the error: `(...) utils\display.ts(13,37) - TS7006: Parameter 'level' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

EDIT:

I found that changing the utility file to use a `.tsx` extension solves the problem so it's definitely something in the config. Here is my tsconfig.json in case anyone can identity the problem:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "watch": true,
    "outDir": "React/build",
    "rootDir":  "./React/"
  },
  "include": [
    "React"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "React/build/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Note that this is a hybrid project and all React/Typescript components are under the React directory. Is it possible this is a webpack config issue?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: There's so much boilerplate to run this stuff - should I post my webpack.config.js, tsconfig.json, entry point file, etc.?

Comment: Which line of code is the one that's showing the error?

Comment: The error indicates it's coming from `utils/display.ts` and that message shouldn't even apply to that line. Can you double check?

Comment: Sorry I messed up my edit/comment. The line number doesn't make sense - maybe because it compiles to js? It is complaining about the `level` parameter in the `displayCourseLevel` function. I get the same error calling any imported function with a parameter passed in.